# The cmd closes when I try to run this code

Tags: c, string

The program should receive a string and then check how often each letter is mentioned.

I have done this much so far (I will only check for the letter `A` in this stage)

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int i=0;
    int l,k;
    int r=10;
    char list[10][10] ;
    /* recieve a strng*/
    char str[10] ;
    fgets(str, 10, stdin);
    str[10] = 0;

    /*initialise list[] to -'s */
    for (l = 0; l < 10; l++) {
        for(k=0; k<10; k++) {
            list[l][k]='-' ;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    /*checks if the letter== "A" if yes replace with * */
    for ( i = 0; i < 10 ; ++i) {
        if (str[i]== 97 ) {
            list[r][0]='*';
            r--;
        }
    }

    /*print the second list[] */
    for (l = 0; l < 10; l++) {
        for(k=0; k<10; k++) {
            printf("%c  ", list[l][k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've tested it before adding the reading string code and it worked, but it's not what I wanted :/

```
char list[10];
fgets(str, 10, stdin);
str[10] = 0;
```

any ideas where should I be focusing to make it work again ? 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The problem, as I see it is in

```
 list[r][0]='*';
```

here, the value of `r` is `10`, which is an out-of-bound access. It invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Remember, `C` arrays use `0`-based indexing. So, for an array like

```
 int arr[10] = {0};
```

the valid index will be 0 to 9.

Apart from that, using the direct ASCII values of letters, like `if (str[i] == 97 )` is not very portable approach. You should use `if ( str[i] == 'A')` for better.

That said, I'm not very sure about the logic of your code, it does not do what you *intend* it to do, from any angle.